# How to put recorded macro on separated sheets

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Sheets("JULY 1, 2015 DAY").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("I8:I11,I23:I28,V9:V18").Select
    Range("V9").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("I8:I11,I23:I28,V9:V18,V23:V46").Select
    Range("V23").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("JULY 1, 2015 DAY").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

This is the generated code of the macro i want to use on several sheets, what code should i add?

Comment: What are the names of the 'several sheets'?

Comment: `I want to use it on several sheets`: Is every sheet has the same range as per the above code?

Comment: i only recorded this on a single sheet, i just want to do the same on the following sheets, do i need to input every name of the sheet to the code?

the sheet has the same range as per the above code.

Comment: If there was a date range, then it may be possible to format a sequence of dates into worksheet names but you are providing no specifics here beyond the first worksheet name.

Comment: @VawnHarveyGalanza - do you mean you want to be able to run this macro on whatever happens to be the active sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes i just want to run this macro on whatever sheet is active.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code based upon an array of the worksheet names.

```
Sub Create_CF_Rules()
    Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant

    vWSs = Array("JULY 1, 2015 DAY", "JULY 2, 2015 DAY", "JULY 3, 2015 DAY")

    For w = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
        With Sheets(vWSs(w))
            .Unprotect
            With .Range("I8:I11,I23:I28,V9:V18,V23:V46")
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=0"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 5296274
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            End With
            .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

Just edit the `vWSs = Array("...` to include all of the worksheet names that you want to add new CF rules to. There was no mention of deleting existing rules so I did not cover that.

Answer (score 0):

This will operate on which ever sheet is currently active:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, fc As FormatCondition

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Unprotect

    Set fc = ws.Range("I8:I11,I23:I28,V9:V18,V23:V46").FormatConditions.Add( _
                      Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=0")
    With fc
        .SetFirstPriority
        .StopIfTrue = False
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5296274
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried your code but it did not work, the worksheet got unprotected but the rule supposed to be added did not add.

thank you for your answer.

Comment: Works fine for me. Try clearing any existing CF before running the code on the sheet.